# Comparing a double in an array and returning index number

Tags: java, arrays, double, equality

```
public int index(double dest){
    int index = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<coords.length; i++){
            if((dest-coords[i])<1 && (dest-coords[i])>-1){
                index = i;
            }
        }
        return index;
    }
```

Basically, I have an array "coords" of doubles. I want to write a method index(double dest) which inputs a double, find which index in the array contains this double and return the index integer.

While testing, I am 100% sure my input double is existent in the array and  are numerically equal. However, when I run the method, it always return me 0, or the value at which int index was declared, it seems like the for loop doesn't run at all.

Thanks!

Comment: what values (test values) are you inputting for `dest`?

Comment: `index` should be initially equal to `-1` which indicates that it is not found. Also, consider breaking the loop once you reach the right index.

Comment: I'm inputting a double, specifically 75.0. My coords[] is something like {15.0,45.0,75.0,105.0,135.0};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to representation of floating numbers (float, double) basically you shouldn't compare them without using deltas, or please use BigDecimal instead and construct instances of those class from string representation of the number.

```
double number1 = 0.11234;
double number2 = 0.11234;
double delta = 0.01;
boolean areEqual = Math.abs(number1 - number2) <= delta;
```

Comment: Sure, and I think that storing those values as double isn't the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
public int index(double destination){
int index = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<coords.length; i++){
        if((dest-coordsX[i])<1 && (destX-coordsX[i])>-1){
            index = i; // This gets overwritten as there is no break statement
            break; // Break out of the loop, the first time this becomes true
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just compare the array value directly against the input?

```
if (dest == coords[i]) { //...
```

But a second problem is initializing `index` to 0.  In this case, a return value of `0` could mean it was found at index position `0` or it could mean it wasn't found at all.  Conventionally `-1` is returned if it's not found at all.  Trying initializing `index` to `-1` so `-1` gets returned if the values isn't found in the array.

If the values in the array are not distinct, then you won't be returning the first index that matches, it will be the last index.  Place a `break` inside the `if` for a match to break out of the `for` loop once you've found a match.

Additionally, comparing floating point numbers brings up its own mess: Please read http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm